# Conversion of Interval data to ordinal data

Tags: data-mining, dataset, statistics, data-cleaning, data

I recently learned about Level of measurements and I am really confused in this MCQ where I think the right answer is a and d both.
Lets say the three participants finished the race in 45 seconds,35 seconds and 30 seconds, this is a interval data since there is fixed order and 0 has no meaning and if we convert it to ordinal 30s becomes first 35s second and 45 second third,according to this option a perfectly fits. What am i missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion `etc.` is playing key role here. Ordinal data must have the fixed length, which is not in this case as we can go on even further as `1st,2nd,3rd,4th,..` and so on. There is no end to this. You can argue that there must be fixed number of runners(say 50) and hence we have only 1-50 rank. But it is not mentioned in question hence this assumption is not valid.

If no of atheletes participating were mentioned then you're right.